# Ylraphon - Forgotten Realms - Anyone have info?

Tags: forgotten-realms

Does anyone know of specifics about the city of Ylraphon in the Forgotten Realms, beside the info in "The City of Ravens Bluff"?

Any websites that are up to date with some good content?

Answer (score 5):

Here's something from the Internet Archive:

http://web.archive.org/web/20010718003823/http://www.netspace.org/~dwb/vast/ylraphon.html

Comment: That's awesome! Thx!